Mail form stopped sending success message
I'm not getting the success message , some times t will work but more time it will not. Any help would be most welcome - I'm much better at DIY than this stuff, come to think of it I'm not very good at this!
Thank you
send-email-ajax.js
var form = $('#contact-form');

$(document).ready(function () {
  form.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    sendEmail();
  });
});

function sendEmail() {
  var dataStr = form.serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://*********/mail/send-email.php",
    data: dataStr,
    success: function (result) {
      if (result == "success") {
        form.trigger("reset");
        showMessage(true, "Message successfully- we will reply soon..Message réussi - nous vous répondrons bientôt.");
      } else {
        showMessage(false, result);
      }
    }
  });
}

function showMessage(valid, msg) {
  var msgClasses;
  if (valid) {
    msgClasses = "alert alert-success";
  } else {
    msgClasses = "alert alert-danger";
  }
  $("#result-message")
    .removeClass()
    .addClass(msgClasses)
    .text(msg);
}

PHP code:
<?php
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    // redirect them to your desired location
    header('location: /index.html');
    exit;
}

    $to = "*******@hotmail.com";   
    $from = "no_reply@*******";
    $subject = "New Message From Website";
    $error = "";
    $body = "";
    // Filter Spam
    if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] != ''){
        echo "success";
        exit(0);
    }

    foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
        if($param_name == 'url') {
            // Do not include spam filter variable
            continue;
        }
        $body .= ucwords(str_replace("_", " ", $param_name)) . ": " . $param_val . "\n";
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $to = $_POST['email']; 
    $subject = $_POST['name'];
    $from = "******@puy-robin.co.uk";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    }

    if($from != "") {
        $success = mail($to, $subject, $body, "From:".$from);
    } else {
        $error = "Email is required";
    }
    
    if ($success && $error == ""){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        if($error == ""){
            echo "Something went wrong :(";
        } else {
            echo $error;
        }
    } 
?>

I'm not sure what to do - this is far beyond me.

We can't really do anything without seeing your PHP code and error messages from your server's error log.

Hi,
Thank you for your reply, I had a problem when first posting, with too much code.
Heres the php code, I will try to find the error log - but I'm not sure there will be one as the mail is being sent.

Sorry I'm having a problem poting he PHP code - keep getting a message too long by 670 characters.. The code is only 50 lines any idea what to to ?

Sorry but the only way I can find is posting it as a link...
https://puy-robin.co.uk/text/php.TXT

Post your code by editing your question, not by posting a comment.

I tried to edit it but it keeps saying too much code..... So I'm stuck!

One issue is that you're not actually using PHPMailer. You're using PHP's built-in mail() function, which requires rather more work on your part. You should also be aware that this is a spam gateway, allowing anyone to send email with content of their choosing to any email address. You're also missing all sorts of critical headers, resulting in malformed email that is unlikely to work. I recommend starting again using the PHPMailer Ajax contact form example.

If the php script you call returns an error code (500 for example), you cant catch it with "success:" in javascript but rather with a "error" callback function. Also when you say it works sometimes, do you get the success message everytime the message is sent ?

The email is sent every time, but the form is not clearing or the success message only shows now and then.

I'm really at a loss -  the whole thing is giving my brain shockwaves. Can someone point me to something that works, which I can just paste into our website.
